# Fragment created twice with navigation controller

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-navigation-graph

In the app, we start a new activity holding a fragment, let's call it A. Recently navigation component was added and transitions follow the navigation graph.

So initially it is started by

```
        navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val graphInflater = navController.navInflater
        val navGraph = graphInflater.inflate(R.navigation.something_graph)

        val startDestination: Int = something

        navGraph.startDestination = startDestination
        navController.setGraph(navGraph, intent.extras)
```

Afterward, the user makes some actions, invokes a new fragment, let's say fragment B, and then we need to get back to fragment A.

Currently, this is done by

```
findNavController().navigate(SomethingGraphDirections.actionGlobalNavSomethingFragment(action, destination))
```

Unfortunately this causes fragment A (not activity), to be called twice as a new instance, and then delete is called as described similarly to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257824/android-ondestroy-called-after-oncreate).

I can verify it by printing on the log `this` statements.

```
Activity com.sen.osmo.ui.SomethingActivity@aad8485 onCreate
Fragment SomethingFragment{1c32bd3} (325a1bc9-d922-49ff-8d0a-65e35427d109) id=0x7f0901c8} onCreateView

action
Fragment SomethingFragment{fd9bbac} (eedc20a5-49b1-481c-8045-4cd60c427c78) id=0x7f0901c8} onCreateView
Fragment SomethingFragment{1c32bd3} (325a1bc9-d922-49ff-8d0a-65e35427d109) id=0x7f0901c8} onDestroy

normal end of cycle and actions 

Fragment SomethingFragment{fd9bbac} (eedc20a5-49b1-481c-8045-4cd60c427c78) id=0x7f0901c8} onDestroy
Activity com.sen.osmo.ui.SomethingActivity@aad8485 onDestroy
```

Trying the old code instead of `findNavController().navigate` solves this issue somewhat. which is

```
        if (fragmentManager!!.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            fragmentManager!!.popBackStack()
        } else {
           ...
        }
        fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().remove(this).commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

The result is on create called twice but on the same instance, and no onDestroy is called.

```
Activity onCreate com.sen.osmo.ui.SomethingActivity@96035a6
Fragment onCreateView, savedInstance: true SomethingFragment{44b835a} (d5190920-63a8-4356-bf02-41936dd710a5) id=0x7f0901c8}

action
Fragment onCreateView, savedInstance: true SomethingFragment{44b835a} (d5190920-63a8-4356-bf02-41936dd710a5) id=0x7f0901c8}

Fragment onDestroy SomethingFragment{44b835a} (d5190920-63a8-4356-bf02-41936dd710a5) id=0x7f0901c8}
Activity onDestroy com.sen.osmo.ui.SomethingActivity@96035a6
```

**Is this approach correct??**

However, this is a deprecated method now and as I found we should use

```
   requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
```

but this gives an exception of

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager.
```

**So eventually what solution should we use? Is there a way to use the navigation controller to pop the fragment B so as to go back to fragment A without using navigate ?**

Comment: actually no, should we ? The app is not navigated using the graph, only the operations regarding one specific activity and those two fragments

Comment: @memres could you please remove the name of the graph **_graph from your comment? Its my mistake to include the name on the question, i have edited it.

Comment: added it to manifest, nothing changed

Comment: I removed my first comment. Was not able to edit.

No, you should not have nav_graph in both manifest and code.
I had a similar problem with two instances of a fragment. The reason was, I had the nav graph twice. Once in AndroidManifest and once in code like you. Removing NavGraph from AndroidManifest solved my issue. But i think there is another problem in your case.

Comment: thank you for the comments, unfortunately it seems to be another problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, instead of navigating back to the fragment you want, you need to pop them from the backstack. This doesnt create new instances and the lifecycle is correct.

```
            findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.nav_something_fragment, false)
```

Finally also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63186749/2897683) which says the same